# Dynamic View Creation in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, sdk3.0

can any one please tell me how to create Dynamic views in iphone. 
And I want to know like what is difference between custom views and dynamic views in iphone.

Acutally i went throught google but i didn't find any proper answer.

And I have one more question is like can we create all the views manually in the coding iteslf like the one we create using a Interface bulder and save it as a .nib. how can it be done?can any one please explain me this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> And I want to know like what is difference between custom views and dynamic views in iphone.

They are two different concepts. Apples and oranges.

A "custom view" generally refers to a subclass of `UIView`.

A "dynamic view" might imply a `UIView` that is loaded dynamically depending on control flow through your application.

> And I have one more question is like can we create all the views manually in the coding iteslf like the one we create using a Interface bulder and save it as a .nib. how can it be done?can any one please explain me this.

```
UIView someView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a view manually with code and then make it a nib file.

For Dynamic view I'm not sure what you mean. Describe what you want to achieve in the end. 
Custom View are normally views that you have coded by extending UIView or whatever modifying it to fit your needs. Dynamic view's = view you've coded instead of using IB ??!

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I too think the same for Dynamic Views.Coding views manually instead of usind an IB.but I am not clear.